# Split an array then sort the parts by date

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Considering this array of objets :

```
struct Product {
    var isFresh: Bool
    var date: String
}

let products = [Product(isFresh: true, date: "2012-11-05T15:56+0000"),
                Product(isFresh: false, date: "2017-11-05T15:56+0000"),
                Product(isFresh: true, date: "2019-11-05T15:56+0000"),
                Product(isFresh: false, date: "2014-11-05T15:56+0000"),
                Product(isFresh: true, date: "2013-11-05T15:56+0000"),
]
```

How can I write a function which split the array in two parts (isFresh & !isFresh) then sort the two parts by date and put in the top of the list the products marked as isFresh = true.

I manage the first part :

```
private func handleProducts(_ products: [Product]) -> [Product] {

    return Dictionary(grouping: products) { $0.isFresh }
        .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
        .flatMap { $0.value }
}
```

Comment: You should store your date as a `Date`, then this becomes trivial

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `sorted(by:)` twice to get an array of 2 arrays and then merge them using `flatMap`

```
let fresh = [products.filter { $0.isFresh }.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date}), 
             products.filter { !$0.isFresh }.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date})]
            .flatMap {$0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, after grouping your products into a dictionary, you want to sort the individual arrays of products for each, you can use `mapValues`, e.g.:

```
let results = Dictionary(grouping: products) { $0.isFresh }
    .mapValues { $0.sorted { $0.date < $1.date } }           // sort the subarrays of products within freshness categories
    .sorted { $0.key && !$1.key }                            // sort by freshness
    .flatMap { $0.value }                                    // flatten the subarrays of products
```

(Note, you’re using `$0.key < $1.key`, but Booleans do not have inherent sorting order, which is why I used the `$0.key && !$1.key` pattern.)

But if you really just want a flat array of products, sorting by freshness first and then by date, I’d do just that:

```
let results = products.sorted {
    if $0.isFresh != $1.isFresh { return $0.isFresh }
    return $0.date < $1.date
}
```

---

Unrelated, while your date strings are sortable because their alphabetical sorting happens to be consistent with their chronological sorting, we’d generally use `Date` objects instead to eliminate any ambiguity and not make sorting contingent on the particular string representation of the dates.

So I’d suggest making the `date` property a `Date` type, and using a date formatter to convert these strings to `Date` objects when populating this array of `Product` objects.

Answer (score -1):

First, sort your product array by date

```
products.sort {
    $0.date > $1.date
}
```

Then, apply filter as you require:-

```
let freshProductArr = products.filter {
    return $0.isFresh == true
}

let staleProductArr = products.filter {
    return $0.isFresh == false
}
```

If you want to keep the same array:-

```
products.sort {
   ($0.date > $1.date)
}

products.sort {
     $0.isFresh && !$1.isFresh
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the same array